# Validate Json Request Body Spring boot Rest api

Tags: json, spring-boot, validation, encryption, input

I have created rest API using sprint boot microservices. The request that is coming from Angular is AES encrypted so it comes as a single string. I want to validate the request after decrypting to JSON Key: values.

The request coming from angular in encrypted format than from controller sent to Nodes Js for decrypting. Once it is decrypted and received again in my services in key pair then I want to validate all attributes and their values. How can I do this?

[pleae check the code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfixE.png)

It throws validation error on email as the email param is string and not in email format but actually it is email in encrypted format. Please let me know how i implement this type of validation on request body.

Comment: Can you please share what you have done and what issue you are facing so that we can help you solve that issue.

Comment: I have added the screen shot of the code. As could not post the code in body.

Comment: Code : https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfixE.png